# how do you center columns/rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, center

I have html code that makes a 3 by 3 table with images in each square div. This is the code for the html (basically three rows and 3 columns in each row). I want to place the 3 by 3 table in the center of the page (horizontally) but I'm not sure how to do so. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thank you!

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class = "col-md-4">
            <div class ="boxed">
                <a href="bucket-list.html"><img class="grayscale" src="img6.jpg" width="220px"height="220px"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-md-4">
            <div class ="boxed">
                <a href="christmas.html"><img class="grayscale" src="img1.png" width="220px"height="220px"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-md-4">
            <div class ="boxed">
                <img class="grayscale" src="uiuc.png" width="220px"height="220px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class = "col-md-4">
            <div class ="boxed">
                <img class="grayscale"src="img4.png" width="220px"height="220px">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-md-4">
            <div class ="boxed">
                <img class="grayscale"src="swe.png" width="220px"height="220px"> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-md-4">
            <div class ="boxed">
                <img class="grayscale" src="fashion2.png" width="220px"height="220px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class = "col-md-4">
            <div class ="boxed">
                <img class="grayscale" src="india.png" width="220px"height="220px">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-md-4">
            <div class ="boxed">
                <img class="grayscale"src="nielsen.png" width="220px"height="220px">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-md-4">
            <div class ="boxed">
                <img class="grayscale" src="city.png" width="220px"height="220px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the css code:

```
.boxed {
    border:2.24px solid white;
    width:225px;
    height:225px;
    background: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: "center" as in _horizontal_ centre or _vertical_ centre?

Comment: Unless you are explicitly overriding the bootstrap default styles, your columns are in the centre of the screen (http://www.bootply.com/WAlNaWZVt1). Perhaps you actually want to centre the images in the columns? In which case you can use `text-align:center` (http://www.bootply.com/bi3d6WilwH)

Comment: i added the text-align: center the columns still aren't centered :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `.boxed` elements have a fixed width you can use `margin: 0 auto;` to centre them in you columns:

```css
[class^="col-"] {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.boxed {
    border:2.24px solid white;
    width:225px;
    height:225px;
    background: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="boxed">
              <a href="bucket-list.html"><img class="grayscale" src="http://placehold.it/220x220" width="220px" height="220px"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="boxed">
                <a href="christmas.html"><img class="grayscale" src="http://placehold.it/220x220" width="220px" height="220px"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="boxed">
                <img class="grayscale" src="http://placehold.it/220x220" width="220px" height="220px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="boxed">
                <img class="grayscale" src="http://placehold.it/220x220" width="220px" height="220px">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="boxed">
                <img class="grayscale" src="http://placehold.it/220x220" width="220px" height="220px"> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="boxed">
                <img class="grayscale" src="http://placehold.it/220x220" width="220px" height="220px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="boxed">
                <img class="grayscale" src="http://placehold.it/220x220" width="220px" height="220px">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="boxed">
                <img class="grayscale" src="http://placehold.it/220x220" width="220px" height="220px">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="boxed">
                <img class="grayscale" src="http://placehold.it/220x220" width="220px" height="220px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without having access to the rest of the Bootstrap styles, it's unclear if any might interfere with the styles below. But, absent any style clashes, the styles below will order the `<div class ="boxed">` into a 3x3 grid and horizontally center `<div class="container">`:

```
.container {
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 689px;
margin: 12px auto;
}

.boxed {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
border:2.24px solid white;
width:225px;
height:225px;
background: #ffffff;
}

.col-md-4:nth-of-type(3n+1) .boxed {
clear: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the entire table centered on the whole page, wrap all the code in another div.

```
    <div align="center">
    <div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class = "col-md-4">
        <div class ="boxed">
            <a href="bucket-list.html"><img class="grayscale" src="img6.jpg" width="220px"height="220px"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-4">
        <div class ="boxed">
            <a href="christmas.html"><img class="grayscale" src="img1.png" width="220px"height="220px"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-4">
        <div class ="boxed">
            <img class="grayscale" src="uiuc.png" width="220px"height="220px">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class = "col-md-4">
        <div class ="boxed">
            <img class="grayscale"src="img4.png" width="220px"height="220px">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-4">
        <div class ="boxed">
            <img class="grayscale"src="swe.png" width="220px"height="220px"> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-4">
        <div class ="boxed">
            <img class="grayscale" src="fashion2.png" width="220px"height="220px">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class = "col-md-4">
        <div class ="boxed">
            <img class="grayscale" src="india.png" width="220px"height="220px">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-4">
        <div class ="boxed">
            <img class="grayscale"src="nielsen.png" width="220px"height="220px">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-4">
        <div class ="boxed">
            <img class="grayscale" src="city.png" width="220px"height="220px">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```